# kevent() reported about an closed connection error

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, server, freebsd

we are using FreeBSD, nginx, php-fpm in our server for php (yii) application. Sometimes

```
kevent() reported about an closed connection (54: Connection reset by peer) while  reading response header from upstream...
```

occured in server log file and website response reach time out. Service php-fpm restart solves the problem. Website is news website and new news (images, videos) add to website regularly. Always 150-250 visitors on website. Visits do not rise when down happen. Website database size is 3GB and size of files 3TB.  
   What can cause this problem? What can best value be for buffer size, cache memory, request per second for config settings on this website? 
Any suggestion can help